# MATLAB axes colors change when writing a GIF

Tags: matlab, matplotlib, colors, gif, axes

Relevant Information: MATLAB R2015b, Mac

I am currently trying to write a GIF from a series of datasets (txt files) I took. I have no trouble writing the GIF file, however, when played back (in PowerPoint) or previewed in the OS X Finder, the axes labels change in color. In addition to the color change, I receive this warning:

> Warning: Image data contains values that are out of range.  Out of range values will be given the nearest valid value.

Currently, I grab all the data files in the directory, plot them, grab each frame, and put them into a GIF. Here is my code:

```
%Create MATLAB movie from plots
clearvars
%addpath('C:\Users\ucmuser\Documents\MATLAB')
filename='cooldown_movie.gif';
ext_in='txt';
[~,listing]=f_search(ext_in);
[r,~]=size(listing);
listing=natsortfiles(listing);
F=figure;

%r=20 is used for quick debugging (original is 460 files).
r=20;
% y=linspace(1,2*pi,100);
% x=linspace(1,100,100);
%C(1,1,1,r)=0;
for i=1:r
        A=dlmread(listing{i});
        listing{i}=strrep(listing{i},'_','\_');
        x=A(1,:); %X Array
        y=A(2,:); %Y Array
            plot(x./1E9,y.*1E3,'-','LineWidth',1.2,...
                'Color',[0.8500 0.3250 0.0980]);
   grid off
    xlabel('Frequency (GHz)','FontSize',18,'FontWeight','bold')
    ylabel('Voltage (mV)','FontSize',18,'FontWeight','bold')
    title('Cooldown Movie','FontSize',24,'FontWeight','bold')
    G(i)=getframe(gcf);
    drawnow
    frame = G(i);
%    im = frame2im(frame);
    [C(:,:,1,i),map] = rgb2ind(frame.cdata,256,'nodither');
%     if r == 1;
%         imwrite(C,map,filename,'gif','LoopCount',Inf,'DelayTime',0);
%     else
%         imwrite(C,map,filename,'gif','WriteMode','append','DelayTime',0);
%     end
end
imwrite(C,map,filename,'gif','LoopCount',Inf,'DelayTime',0);
```

A sample image is shown below. The axes labels change in color. If I turn on the grid, the effect is even more apparent with the grid changing in grayscale intensity. I've tried setting limits and the effect is still present.

[image: Sample graph displaying axes labels color change]

Comment: This is likely due to the gif's disposal method. Have you considered manually specifying `xlim` and `ylim` so that the axes aren't constantly changing. That should clean up your video.

Comment: Yes I have tried setting the limits and it doesn't help very much.

Comment: If I set the axis limits, I get a weird background flashing color effect on the figure.

Comment: Instead of using MATLAB to write to GIF, I would simply let the actual MATLAB figure animate and use a capture tool like [LICEcap](http://www.cockos.com/licecap/) do that for you. Try that instead of writing a GIF to file using MATLAB syntax and see how that works for you.  If it helps, I have never written MATLAB code to ever create animated GIFs from multiple MATLAB plots. I just let LICEcap capture the figure window for me. As an example, see this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29948697/switching-values-to-plot-using-keyboard-input/29948924#29948924

Comment: Yes, there is that option. The downside is that LICEcap records at the speed which MATLAB plots the figure, which happens to be much slower than the GIF file with a delay of 0 seconds between images. I suppose I could still reduce the number of frames in LICEcap to increase the playback speed after it has been recorded.

Answer (score 0):

I've found a solution for the time being although I'm not quite sure why it works. I started going through the figure properties and turned **off** the ***GraphicsSmoothing*** property (type `F=figure;F.GraphicsSmoothing='off';` before the "for loop"). This seemed to fix the problem as well as clear the original *out of range* error.

With the GraphicsSmoothing property turned "on" and going through the first 20 data files, I have a maximum indexed color value of 22 via `max(max(max(C)))`. Performing the same code with the GraphicsSmoothing turned "off" yields a maximum value of 4.

I am attaching two images displaying the extreme color differences with the GraphicsSMoothing turned on and off.

[GraphicsSmoothing turned On (default)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WJsXr.gif)

[GraphicsSmoothing turned Off](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VimT6.gif)

If someone knew why this is the case, I would greatly appreciate it.

UPDATE: I attempted to use this solution with `grid on` and the background border turned orange. I am confused on this whole issue.